# My prefix lets us open doors, My suffix is crucial for doors

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- My prefix lets us open doors.
- My suffix is crucial for doors.
- My infix is where we get pork.
- My whole is why pianos work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

> keyboard

My prefix lets us open doors.

> That sounds an awful lot like a "key" lol

My suffix is crucial for doors.

> It's kinda essential to have a "board"... otherwise your door is just a hinge

My infix is where we get pork.

> Large pigs are often called a boar

My whole is why pianos work.

> The keyboard is what the player presses in order to push a hammer that strikes a tuned wire, which makes the sound.

Answer (score 8):

Since I think Ankit already has it, I went down a rabbit hole to create an "out-of-the-box" answer as a thought exercise. Lot's of metaphors and it's all a stretch... Maybe someone can help me improve?

> Sounder

My prefix lets us open doors.

> So - looking at metaphorical doors, a definition of "so" is "and then; as the next step", taking the next step allows up to open new doors (opportunities).

My suffix is crucial for doors.

> under - literal doors, if there's nothing under them, they serve no purpose.

My infix is where we get pork.

> a sounder is a collective noun for a group of pigs, we get our pork from the one in the middle ;)

My whole is why pianos work.

> a sounder is an alternative name for the hammer that actually strikes the piano string and creates sound.

Obviously not as good as the other answer (why I voted for it), leaving here for anyone curious/maybe inspire another?

Comment: Lol I like the ingenuity.